# reading Autosave'd NSSortDescriptor's from NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an application that display an array of objects in a 6 column NSTableView. The user can display the list via whichever column sort order they prefer. The NSTableView in the XIB file uses the autosave feature so that the sort order is preserved over application launches. All is working well.

There are times though when I want to know what the user's sort order preference is *before* this particular NSTableView get's loaded.  I'd like to read those sort ordering preferences out of the Preferences file to sort the array according to their preference, but without having loaded from the XIB file that contains that NSTableView.

I can see the sort descriptors saved in my app's standardUserDefaults Preferences file. It's an array with 12 items in it (0-11) and the even numbered elements (0,2,4,6,8,10) are shown as Data and the odd numbered elements(1,3,5,7,9,11) are Boolean's.

The documentation says that NSSortDescriptor conforms to NSSecureCoding, but if I instantiate an NSKeyedUnarchiver with one of the Data elements, I get:
"non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver"
If I use an NSUnarchiver, I get:
"*** End of archive encountered prematurely at 58"

In either case, the Boolean elements in the array are the "ascending" flag property of the NSSortDescriptor and so it wouldn't even be included if doing the above. So I guess I need to combine the 2 elements in some way to get a coded sort descriptor? Does anyone have an idea of how to decode the "autosaved" sort descriptors?

Answer (score 1):

this solution worked for me: (please ignore all the ZSAsserts)
its a method in a subclass/category of NSTableView

```html
-(void) zsSetTableLayoutFromAutosaveName:(NSString*) autosaveName{
    
    // set initial sortDescriptors
    int i = 0;
    NSString* columnName = @"";
    NSMutableArray* sortDescriptors = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (id data in [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NSTableView Sort Ordering %@",autosaveName]]) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            ZSAssert([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]);
            columnName = [NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        }
        else {
            ZSAssert([data isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]);
            BOOL ascending = [((NSNumber*) data) boolValue];
            [sortDescriptors addObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:columnName ascending:ascending]];
        }
        i++;
    }
    [self setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    
    // set intial hidden-state
    for (NSData* data in [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NSTableView Hidden Columns %@",autosaveName]]) {
        ZSAssert([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]);
        NSString* colName = [NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        ZSAssert([colName isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);
        NSTableColumn* tc = [self tableColumnWithIdentifier:columnName];
        if (!tc.isHidden){
            [tc setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
    
    // set initial width
    i = 0;
    for (id data in [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NSTableView Columns %@",autosaveName]]) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            ZSAssert([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]);
            columnName = [NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        }
        else {
            ZSAssert([data isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);
            float width = ((NSString*) data).floatValue;
            [[self tableColumnWithIdentifier:columnName] setWidth:width];
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    [self setAutosaveName:autosaveName]; // from now on, every change made to the table should be automatically persisted into user-defaults
    [self setAutosaveTableColumns:YES];
}
```